# NSOperation not continuing after "attributesOfItemAtPath:error " method

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an NSOperation and am inserting the operation into an operationqueue. I need to set the max concurrent operations to 1. I'll be inserting many such operations from time to time. But I need atmost one operation to be executed at a time. At that time other operations will wait, and once the previos operation finish its execution next operation in the queue will start executing and so on.

But when I debuggged I found that one of my operation is basically blocking all other operations. The operation is not doing aything after the call

> NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];

Since maxoperationscount is 1, all other operatons are kinda blocked.

Anyone got any idea, why it's stopping execution after the statement?

Comment: On the simulator, when you pause and look at the stack, where is it sitting?

Comment: that is how I debugged. This thread seems to be hanged in the above line of code. I resumed and waited for a long time. It was still there only.

Comment: Yes, but where in the system code was it sitting?